# Serializing implemented class given a java interface using Jersy Moxy in Jax-Rs

Tags: java, rest, jaxb, jax-rs, moxy

I am trying to implement RESTful web service using JAX-RS. I am using Jersy MOXY 2.16 as JSON Provider. Following are the examples of DTOs I am using.

```
@XmlSeeAlso(value = { B.class, C.class })
public interface A extends Serializable {

}
```

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(propOrder={"id", "name"})
public class B implements A{
    
    @XmlAttribute
    private int id;
    
    @NotEmpty
    @NotNull
    private String name;
}
```

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(propOrder={"id", "name"})
public class C implements A{
    
    @XmlAttribute
    private int id;
    
    @NotNull
    @NotEmpty
    private String name;
}
```

I did not create any Provider class or applied any custom configs to this. Now if I try to send POST request with JSON body of implemented classes i.e B or C, it's successfully getting deserialized to respective DTOs.

```
@Path("/b")
public class ResourceB{
    
    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response add(@Valid B b) throws Exception {
        
    }
```

But if I try having interface A as POST request method parameter and send either B or C class JSON body, I am getting `500 internal server error` with no error message.

```
@Path("/b")
public class ResourceB{
    
    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response add(@Valid A a) throws Exception {

    }
```

Would like to hear a solution or a suggestion for this.